# Change of canonical sheaf in blowing-up

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose $Y$ is a singular projective variety defined over (for simplicity) $\mathbb{Q}$, then from Prop 7.5 of Hartshorne, the dualizing sheaf of $Y$ is defined and let's denote it by $\omega_Y$.

Let $Z$ be the singular locus of $Y$ and for simplicity, let's assume $Z$ is irreducible. Now let $X$ be the blow-up of $Y$ at $Z$ with exceptional divisor $D$
\begin{equation}
\pi:X \rightarrow Y
\end{equation}
What is the relation between the dualizing sheaf $\omega_X$ (which is a line bundle as $X$ is smooth) and the pull-back of $\omega_Y$? e.g is it still true that 
\begin{equation}
\omega_X=\pi^* \omega_Y+D
\end{equation}
just like the smooth case?

Comment: @JeskoHüttenhain Hartshorne, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: No. In general all we can say is that the canonical divisor on $X$ differs from the pullback by an exceptionally supported divisor. For example, if $Y$ is a surface with a rational singularity, that exceptionally supported divisor is actually $0$.

Comment: @JohnBrevik If the $Y$ admits a canonical divisor $D_Y$, i.e. its canonical sheaf is given by a divisor, is the canonical divisor of $X$ equal to $D_Y+D$? Thank you.

Comment: No; see above. As a concrete example, the quadric cone in $\mathbb P^3$ has canonical sheaf $\mathcal O(-1)$ -- a line bundle. Resolving the singularity gives a surface whose canonical sheaf is just the pullback of this one with no exceptional component.

Comment: @JohnBrevik Thank you very much, this is very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, in your post you shouldn't assume that the blow-up of $Z$ gives a nonsingular variety; there may be several blowings-up and normalizations required to resolve the singularity.